# Abrir URL HTTPS (SSL) dentro de la Aplicación Android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview-android

Mi Problema es el siguiente, he creado un  Botón Que llama a un WebView, pero este no me carga la Url, la Url no es http si no https creo que es el motivo por el que no me la abre.
Alguien Me PUEDE Ayudar?

```
public class ActivityRenovar extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.renovar);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    webView=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    webView.loadUrl(
      "https://ws054.juntadeandalucia.es/autenticacion/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fws054.juntadeandalucia.es%2Fapdweb%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin%3Fp_l_id%3D10116%26_58_redirect%3D%252Fapdweb%252Fgroup%252F10210%252F2");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            return false;
    }
    }
    );

};

}
```

Comment: ¿Da algún error? Si puedes ver el error agrégalo a la pregunta editándola, así se te podrá ayudar mejor.

Comment: Gracias Jorge justo era eso lo que necesitaba...solucionado!!!....Sabia que era problema de ssl y el protocolo de certificados no se como agradecértelo me llevo varios días y dolor de cabeza ...jajajja

Answer (score 1):

Para esto necesitas usar configurar **[WebViewClient()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)** a tu `WebView` y mediante la implementación del método [onReceivedSslError()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedSslError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.SslErrorHandler,%20android.net.http.SslError)) usando:

```
 handler.proceed();
```

puedes lograr la carga de la página cuando el certificado no esta autorizado.

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
              ...
              ...
              ...

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
                switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                    case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                        message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                        message = "The certificate has expired.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                        message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                        break;
                    case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                        message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                        break;
                }
                message += "\"SSL Certificate Error\" Do you want to continue anyway?.. YES";

                handler.proceed();
            }

        });
```

Puedes ver en mi caso, puedo incluso revisar mi e-mail que esta dentro de una página SSL dentro de un `WebView`:

[image]

Comment: Este metodo funciona bien pero no está  permitido por google, con este codigo no podras subir la app a la Play store...

Comment: Implementar onReceivedSslError() impide no subir la aplcación a playstore? Donde viste o leiste eso, tengo 2 apps donde tengo este método.

Comment: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387                      Bueno ahí esta la respuesta a tu pregunta y también la solución recientemente subí una app y me encontré con el problema.....gracias a dios pude solucionarlo y ahora trabajo en mejorar un poco el código he implementarlo con SharedPreferences para no mostrar siempre el Alerdialog ....cada vez que se quiera conectar al enlace https .....otra opción es instalar el certificado de la web a la que quieras enlazar.......espero te ayude...