# Saber que acción se realizo en Webview al realizar un pago

Tags: android

Saludos,
Muestro un sitio para realizar pagos utilizan el API de [lemonway](https://webkit.lemonway.fr/)
et alors,
la cosa es que al mostrarlo en el WebView no se como saber si la persona completo el pago, o la cancelo , o simplemente lo ignoro y se salio de la aplicacion,etc.

¿Como saber que se hizo dentro del webview?

```
token=restaurant.getTOKEN();     
wvSitioPago.loadUrl("https://webkit.lemonway.fr/ejemplo/?moneyintoken="+token);
```

Tengo algo asi, simplemente muestro la pagina resultante al meterle un token que me mandan el cual me muestra el sitio de pagos en el webview.

Es la primera vez que utilizo un webview o implemento pagos,
¿algo que me guie?, estoy muy novato en esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes definir un `WebViewClient()` a tu `WebView` y donde puedes detectar las paginas que se cargan al realizar un redireccionamiento carga de página( te recomiendo `onPageStarted()` ), obviamente si tienes el url puedes detectar algún valor com o el token

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url " + request.toString());
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " + url);            
            }

          @Override
             public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
               super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
              Log.i(TAG,"onPageStarted() URL: " + url);
          }


        });

webview.loadUrl(url);
```

> Como saber si la persona completo el pago, o la cancelo , o
>   simplemente lo ignoro y se salio de la aplicacion,etc.

Debes definir cuales son las url que son cargadas al realizar esas operaciones y los parametros que necesitas obtener durante la navegación.

---

Si tienes problemas para cargar la página que usa SSL debes implementar el método onReceivedSslError() de tu WebViewClient que describo en esta respuesta, esto para que pueda funcionar correctamente:

[Abrir URL HTTPS (SSL) dentro de la Aplicación Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64888/abrir-url-https-ssl-dentro-de-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android)

Comment: Maestro, gracias por iluminarme y hacer acto de presencia, es necesario meterlo en el onCreate? o va a funcionar si lo meto en el OnClick de un boton.

Comment: hehe, para esos métodos se llamen, se necesita una interacción de la página dentro del WebView.

Comment: Oh gran Maestro, yo te invoco para preguntarte algo : ¿ Por que el metodo con Override jamas me funciona pero si el que esta deprecado? Tengo que poner mi codigo en el deprecado porque el del override jamas reacciona.

Comment: Haha!!! Eduardo, a que métodos te refieres, el único método obsoleto es : onReceivedError() que se llama si ocurre un error, esto si usas una página https: , si requieres ayuda te sugiero subas tu proyecto a un repositorio GitHub.

Comment: @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,                     
              Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url " + request.toString());
                return true;
            } 

Todo lo que tenga alli adentro , nunca sucede.

Comment: Mi codigo funciona pero teniendolo en el otro, en el primero, el que no tiene Override , pero me marca que esta deprecado, pero es el que funciona. El del URL

Comment: @EduardoRicardez tienes razón Eduardo veo que hay ciertos detalles con OS KitKat anteriores y posteriores para esto que deseas realizar te recomiendo uses onPageStarted()