# Error al usar un WebView, NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Buenas tengo un problema al hacer mi WebView.

```
 05-02 23:38:11.239 29315-29315/srf.lec.noctambuloss E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
 EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: 
 srf.lec.noctambuloss, PID: 29315

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{srf.lec.noctambuloss/srf.lec.noctambuloss.Boliches}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at srf.lec.noctambuloss.Boliches.onCreate(Boliches.java:22)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Mi actividad es boliches:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_boliches);
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.Visorboliches);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        String url = "asdasd645546546";
        view.loadUrl(url);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Cual es tu linea 22 ?

Comment: Mi linea 22 es view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

Comment: Ok, gracias, Entonces el problema es el que describo en mi respuesta, no existe una referencia de el WebView llamado Visorboliches, por lo tanto el valor de view es nulo. @EmilianoRigobello

Comment: Ya encontre el error, de todos los layouts de las densidades de pantalla me quedo uno sin nombrar la ID de la WebView, ahora tengo otra duda, tarda mucho en abrirse el WebView desde la aplicacion, como podria acelerarlo?

Comment: Lo que comentas es un error común cuando agregamos varios layouts. Para acelerarlo creo que los problemas que suceden regularmente porque se acceder a urls que son SSL : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64888/abrir-url-https-ssl-dentro-de-la-aplicaci%C3%B3n-android

Answer (score 1):

Revisa que en realidad se tenga un `WebView` con id `Visorboliches` dentro del layout `activity_boliches.xml`, si no existe, la instancia del `WebView` (view) tiene un valor null:

```
  WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.Visorboliches);
  view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```